# Probably simple php regex

Tags: php, regex

Sorry for the simple question that I could research, but i crashed a database today, been here 12 hours, and want to go home.

I am rotating recursively through files trying to extract city, phone number, and email address so that I can match the city and phone to my database entries and update the users email address. In theory, they could just login with their email and request to reset their password.

heres what i need.  my file contents look like this:

```
> Address : 123 main street City : somecity State/Province : somestate
> Zip/Postal Code : 12345 Country : United States Phone : 1231231234 Fax
> : E-Mail : example@example.com ==== CUSTOMER SHIPPING INFORMATION ===
```

I should note that there is other info before and after the snippet I showed. Can someone please help me with a regex to remove the 3 items? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have line breaks maybe, or this is exact copy of file?

Comment: that is what it looks like when i `print ($filecontents);`

Comment: Are the `>`s actually apart of it too?

Comment: no, someone edited it and added that...  i do believe there is line breaks though, because if i open the file in dreamweaver each data set has its own line

Comment: Post more than just one *record*. This will help determine a more reliable regex. Otherwise, it might match an address with a email later in the file.

Comment: every record is identical, they are actually auto emails from my payment processor with the shipping details of the clients order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, without regex..

```
$string = 'Address : 123 main street City : somecity State/Province : somestate Zip/Postal Code : 12345 Country : United States Phone : 1231231234 Fax : E-Mail : example@example.com ==== CUSTOMER SHIPPING INFORMATION ===';

$string = str_replace(
array(
' ==== CUSTOMER SHIPPING INFORMATION ===',
'Address',
'City',
'State/Province',
'Zip/Postal Code',
'Country',
'Phone',
'Fax',
'E-Mail'
)
, '', $string);

$string = explode(' : ', $string);
unset($string[0]);
print_r($string);
```

Result...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 123 main street 
    [2] => somecity 
    [3] => somestate 
    [4] => 12345 
    [5] => United States 
    [6] => 1231231234 
    [7] => 
    [8] => example@example.com
)
```

If there are linebreaks, something like this...

```
$string = explode("\n", $string);
foreach($string as $value){
    list(, $info) = explode(' : ', $value);
    echo $info . '<br />';
}
```

Solution with regex..

```
$fields = array('City', 'Phone', 'E-mail');
foreach($fields as $field){
    preg_match("#$field : (.*?) #is", $string, $matches);
    echo  "$field : $matches[1]";
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Result:

```
City : somecity
Phone : 1231231234
E-mail : example@example.com
```

Comment: @Jason McCreary, if there are linebreaks, it is much shorter :)

Comment: @Jason McCreary, I've posted regex solution also ;)

Comment: `$info & '<br />'` ??? Perhaps I'm uninformed, but I didn't know bitwise-and could be used for concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Address\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*City\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*State/Province\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*Zip/Postal Code\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*Country\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*Phone\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*Fax\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*E-Mail\s*:\s*(.*?)\s
```

Will work if you rip out the `>` at the start of each line first.

[proof](http://regexpal.com/?flags=s&regex=Address%5Cs%2a%3A%5Cs%2a%28.%2a%3F%29%5Cs%2aCity%5Cs%2a%3A%5Cs%2a%28.%2a%3F%29%5Cs%2aState%2FProvince%5Cs%2a%3A%5Cs%2a%28.%2a%3F%29%5Cs%2aZip%2FPostal%20Code%5Cs%2a%3A%5Cs%2a%28.%2a%3F%29%5Cs%2aCountry%5Cs%2a%3A%5Cs%2a%28.%2a%3F%29%5Cs%2aPhone%5Cs%2a%3A%5Cs%2a%28.%2a%3F%29%5Cs%2aFax%5Cs%2a%3A%5Cs%2a%28.%2a%3F%29%5Cs%2aE-Mail%5Cs%2a%3A%5Cs%2a%28.%2a%3F%29%5Cs&input=Address%20%3A%20123%20main%20street%20City%20%3A%20somecity%20State%2FProvince%20%3A%20somestate%0AZip%2FPostal%20Code%20%3A%2012345%20Country%20%3A%20United%20States%20Phone%20%3A%201231231234%20Fax%0A%3A%20E-Mail%20%3A%20example%40example.com%20%3D%3D%3D%3D%20CUSTOMER%20SHIPPING%20INFORMATION%20%3D%3D%3D%0A)

If you `print_r` that, you'll see the different components.

Note the "dot matches all" modifier. Might be even easier if you rip out newlines too (after you take out the `>`).

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
$test = 
'
> Address : 123 main street City : somecity State/Province : somestate
> Zip/Postal Code : 12345 Country : United States Phone : 1231231234 Fax
> : E-Mail : example@example.com ==== CUSTOMER SHIPPING INFORMATION ===
';

preg_match('@.*City : (.+?) .*? Country : (.+?) Phone : (.+?) .*@si',$test,$res);
var_dump($res);
```

result

```
array
  0 => string '
> Address : 123 main street City : somecity State/Province : somestate
> Zip/Postal Code : 12345 Country : United States Phone : 1231231234 Fax
> : E-Mail : example@example.com ==== CUSTOMER SHIPPING INFORMATION ===
' (length=217)
  1 => string 'somecity' (length=8)
  2 => string 'United States' (length=13)
  3 => string '1231231234' (length=10)
```